# How to configure application on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, launching-application

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC4 that i need to configure on Amazon EC2 server.

But i am new to this and not familiar with this.Currently my application is configured on Azure server.And now i want to shift it on Amazon EC2.

I go through with this video :-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPFoDnjR8e8

> > I have sign up and went to Launch an application.But i did not have the credit card details now.And i used dummy CC details(took from google).

But i guess its not supporting the dummy CC details.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Comment: Dummy CC? Do you expect Amazon to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The basic process is that you need to setup an account with a valid credit card, create an instance thru the aws console, and then use the generated credentials to RDP (Remote Desktop) into the server.

The process of setting up an MVC app (or any program for that matter) is going to be 100% identical to doing it on your own machine - there is no difference once you are able to remote to the instance.